# C Unexpected string returned from function behaviour

Tags: c, string, function

I am quite new to C and I am playing with some string operations. I have encountered quite a strange problem for me while returning a string from a function. My simple program is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char text[] = "abAB";

    char* out = testString(text);

    printf("Result Text: %s", out);
    printf("\n");
}

char* testString(char* input) {
    char* text = copyString(input);

    return text;
}
```

The copyString function defines a simple operation to copy one string to another. It is as follows:

```
char* copyString(char* input) {
    char output[100];

    int index = 0;
    while (input[index] != '\0') {
        output[index] = input[index];
        index++;
    }

    output[index] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```

The problem is that while I am debugging the application, the string I am returning from a function seems to be OK (Visual Studio visualises it well enough) and when the printf line occurs, the string outputted on the stdout is something completely strange and unfamiliar - a smily face. Sadly, I can't post images yet in order to show you what I see in my console as output.

I am using Visual C++ Express 2010 as an IDE if this could be helpful.

Comment: `char output[100];` is a temporary variable, it will be destroyed as soon as `copyString` returns leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: That seems to be a reasonable argument. Well how do you suggest I proceed in order to create a string variable and return it afterwards then?

Comment: With posix a quick and dirty way is to use `strdup`, you'll want to avoid using it in production code however unless you can guarantee that its argument is correctly terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a variable declared within a function, which will cease to exist outside the scope in which it is declared. Use a dynamically allocated char array and then return a pointer to it.

```
char* output = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
...
return output ;
```

**Note** : You are assuming that input string is less than 100 characters. Instead of that, try passing the length of string as a parameter or use `strlen`. Your program will crash if input string has more than 99 characters.

Also as noted in comments, free the memory allocated when you are done using it.

Comment: Do not forget to free this memory after you use that

Comment: I am getting a compile error now which doesn't allow me to create that char arr using the way you specified. I am getting the following error:
A value of type void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type char*

Comment: Just use a cast i.e. `char* output = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: I don't know what result your visual studio compiler gives, when I compile your code in a `gcc` (standard) environment, this is the warning:

`    gcc play.c
    play.c: In function ‘copyStrin g’:
    play.c:12:5: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return output;
     ^
`
Now, this warning clearly states, you want to return a `char*` holding the value of your copied string, but what you are returning is the address of a local variable, which will be destroyed as soon as it get out of scope.

Comment: So, your pointer becomes `dangling pointer`, ie. it is now pointing to any memory location, which is not under your control for now. It could have given you a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) as well.
<br>
What you need to do is declare your output as:

    `char *output = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));`

and then do your operations. It should work fine then.

Comment: I can't format answer in comments !!